# With Python Selenium how can I verify a selected option text with special characters?

Tags: python, selenium, python-unicode

My Select Option (selected) text has appended text: & n b s p ; & n b s p ; & n b s p ; & n b s p ; & # x 2 7 1 4 ; which produces a checkmark (✔) preceded by some spaces.

HTML like:

```
    <label for="PSME">PSME:<select id="PSME" name="PSME"><option value="someuniquenumbershere" selected="selected">Lname, Fname&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#x2714;</option>
<option value="">------------</option>

<option value="someuniquenumbershere">.... lots of options here
```

I'm trying to verify the contents of the option text.
like:

```
PSMEMatch = False
try:
    for option in CPSMEElement.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
        if option.text == self.TestUserName + "    &#x2714;":
            PSMEMatch = True
            break
```

This code never matches the option.text with a true result in the 'if'.
How do I get this 'if' to match the option.text?

I capture the results in a log and I've verified the Element is correct and the code runs without errors, except of course the "if option.text ==" never matches the self.TestUserName + "& n b s p ; & n b s p ; & n b s p ; & n b s p ; & # x 2 7 1 4 ;"

{Yes, I've read the "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)" and the page does contain < m e t a c h a r s e t = " u t f -  8 " >, I'm still lost.}

(I've padded some of the text above with spaces so that SO will properly display the code.)

Thanks

Comment: Does Python not have some kind of String.trim() function?

Comment: Sure: "strip()", but the checkmark needs to be verified and can change to something else that I also need to verify.

Comment: So it's a character encoding problem? Could you read one of the attributes instead, like the `@selected`?

Comment: Yes, it seems like a character encoding thing, and I'd like to verify the text.

Comment: `if option.text.endswith(u'& # x 2 7 1 4 ;')`